# Sharepoint 2010 merging 'wikis' together

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, merge, wiki

I have taken on the task of bringing all of our company's documents, data etc. into the same place and it's all a bit of a mess.

We have various different SharePoint (2010) 'wikis' that have been created and used in different ways and I would like to merge them together as one.

I would like the new wiki to include metadata navigation to make it easy for them to filter and find their content.

Currently, they have wiki libraries, page libraries and publishing libraries and if I try to move pages from one to another (or from one to a new library) it works, but then errors if I try to edit the properties.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Is it possible at all?

Or would I be looking at the nightmare of creating all new pages and copying content one by one?

Answer (score -1):

Wiki pages and publishing pages uses different content types and different columns.  I think it's pretty straight forward if you are just migrating content over from publishing page to wiki pages with a script  but it gets very tricky when web parts are involved.